# Chrome - Vagrant box issue, can't reconnect after a connection with IE/Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, http, vagrant

I have a vagrant (Debian 7 + LAMP) box available via `http://localhost:8087` I use it to develop a site. 
I start the box connect to it via Chrome (v37.0.2062.120 m)
Then I connect to it via IE and browse the site normally.

After this, if I go back to Chrome and refresh the page I get Error code: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED , and I can't connect back to it (via Chrome) meantime, the site works fine in IE or Firefox.

If I do a restart all goes back to normal. However I can reproduce the issue every time.

BTW: I am on windows 7 with vagrant 1.6.3

Comment: When you say restart, what did you actually restart? The box or apache? This looks like a VBox NAT engine name resolution issue. The easiest way to workaround it is to add a public network interface (bridging mode) which will be able to acquire an IP within the same network as your host, then you can use that IP to access the site.

Comment: @TerryWang I am restarting the machine. `vagrant halt` then `vagrant up`

Comment: OK, then it's equivalent to `vagrant reload`.

Comment: Try to add the line in Vagrantfile `vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]` and do a `vagrant reload`. Chrome may have internal DNS caching mechanism.

Comment: @TerryWang tried that but received same behavior. After some mor diggin' seems to be related to chrome's dns cache: `chrome://net-internals/#dns`

Comment: Clear chrome host resolver cache and it should work.

Comment: @TerryWang Yep, tried it a few times and it seems to work sometimes. But not a good solution. After all I think it might be a Chrome bug.

Comment: neither "vb.customize..." nor clearing chrome's dns cache seems to help--only restarting my osx... really annoying